# Confidence interval of the estimated Probability of a Poisson Process

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

If the number of photons arriving from a laser on a detector within a fixed time interval is Poisson($\lambda$) distributed, $P(X=k)= \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$.

If we perform a measurement N times and keep only track of the the number of times we observe X=k as $N_k$, we can estimate P(X=k)=$N_k/N$.

If $\lambda$ is small, and $N$ is large, how can I find the confidence interval of this estimation?

Comment: The situation you describe cannot (correctly) be modeled with a Poisson random variable: it's a *Binomial* experiment.  That leaves us in a quandary: which of these two different questions do you need answered?  Binomial confidence intervals are described in many posts here, so please search our site; otherwise, please indicate why you think your application should be modeled with a Poisson variable.

Comment: Your edit introduces a different contradiction, because there's no connection whatsoever between your estimator and the supposed Poisson distribution.  You're supposed to be estimating $\lambda,$ not the individual probabilities!  So, again, what is your question?  What exactly is your model and what is the parameter you wish to estimate?

Comment: Maybe I am completely confused, but I assume I can estimate $\lambda$ from the data.
Shouldn't I then be able to predict P(X=k) using that lambda? But if my estimate of  $\lambda$  has some variance, wouldn't this also result in some variance on  the prediction of predict P(X=k)?

Comment: Much of that is correct: but in your post you don't describe estimating $\lambda:$ you give separate estimates for every $\Pr(X=k),$ all infinitely many of them; and there's no assurance those estimates would be consistent with any Poisson distribution.  It begins to sound like you wish somehow to estimate $\lambda$ (maybe with the mean of the data?); you have specified some $k$ beforehand; and wish to obtain a confidence interval for $\Pr(X=k).$  I'm just guessing... .